# Can you delete from post_params in a Rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete from the `post_params` hash in my Rails `update` action, but my `delete` call seems like it's being ignored.

```
puts "before: #{post_params.inspect}"
  # output: before {"headline"=>"blah", "tags"=>"foo bar"}
puts "deleted: #{post_params.delete("tags")}"
  # output: deleted: foo bar
puts "after:  #{post_params.inspect}"
  # output: before {"headline"=>"blah", "tags"=>"foo bar"}
  # WHY IS "tags" STILL THERE?
```

Am I making some kind of elementary noob mistake?  This is driving me crazy because it seems so stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure that `post_params` is a method in your controller where you whitelist the attributes of your model and this method returns a new hash instance every time you call it.
This is the reason why `tags` is still there as it wasn't deleted from the actual hash i.e. `params` in the first place.

You should be deleting the `tags` key from the actual hash i.e. `params` and not from the hash returned from `post_params` method call.

For example:

If `params = {"post" => {"headline"=>"blah", "tags"=>"foo bar"}}`

then use `params["post"].delete("tags")`

Comment: Argh.  It totally is a method.  A method I wrote (well, copy/pasted, whatever).  I'm an idiot.

Comment: It happens. :) The attribute whitelisting part at controller level was added in Rails 4. That's where `post_params` is coming from.